# Does Windows10 cut short a webm video made in a browser?

Tags: windows-10, webm

I have made a web application (for fellow Zazzle storekeepers) that creates webm videos of their designs in the browser. For the last approx 7 seconds of the video there is a "call to action" text. For that last 7 seconds, there is no movement in the video.

I'm on a Mac and those last 7 seconds of the video are included in both Firefox and Chrome. Windows 10 users don't get those last 7 seconds and it seems that they are automatically being trimmed off, possibly because there is no movement.

I don't have access to Windows 10 and want to know if that is a feature of Windows 10 browsers. A user has been kind enough to help me some and has tried it in both Firefox and Chrome in Windows 10 and it happens to videos created in both browsers.

**If this is a feature of Windows 10, is there anything I can do about it?**

If you want to try this for yourself, follow the link below, put in the storename **hightonridley** at the prompt and ok it. Once loaded, click the button in the button pane at top left marked "Animate & save video".

Firefox prompts you to download it once made but Chrome goes ahead and downloads it without prompting.
Here's the link: [Video maker](https://niftytoolz.com/npcp/product-stager-for-screenshots.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Windows 10 was unhelpfully truncating the recording at the point at which it detected there was no more movement.
The solution was to introduce a change in the last second of the video. Windows 10 truncating from that point forward then didn't matter.